# Get a URL in a JSP file to run through the controller servlet

Tags: jsp, url, servlets, controller

So I have a list of events (objects). I want to make it so that when you click an event title, additional information will enfold for that event. But if I write it like this, it won't interact with the controller servlet which gives the list of events, it will just go to the EventsOverview.jsp page directly with parameter event=ID. The list of events will be null.

```
List<Event> eventList = (List<Event>) request.getAttribute("eventList");
...
<a href="EventsOverview.jsp?event=<%=e.getID()%>"> <%= e.getTitle() %> </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the URL to the JSP by the URL to the servlet. Assuming that the servlet is in `web.xml` mapped on

```xml
<url-pattern>/EventsOverview</url-pattern>
```

or has the new Servlet 3.0 `@WebServlet("/EventsOverview")` annotation, then you need to replace the link as follows:

```html
<a href="EventsOverview?event=<%=e.getID()%>"> <%= e.getTitle() %> </a>
```

Or, if you adhere the modern (well, almost 10 years old already; make sure that you're reading the proper and up to date books/tutorials) JSP 2.0 way of writing the views:

```html
<a href="EventsOverview?event=${e.id}"><c:out value="${e.title}" /></a>
```

Either way, the servlet's `doGet()` will be called, wherein you can just do the preprocessing job and dispatch the request to the desired JSP to present the results in HTML.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)